# Performance of adding tracking category options using Xero API

Tags: xero-api

I'm trying to add ~20 tracking category options programmatically and I've seen that calls to add the first two values returns in < 1 second, but after that calls timeout.

If I restart with a new session, I see the same behavior (first two calls are quick and then calls timeout).

My question is, is there rate limiting on the Xero API? Has anyone seen behavior similar to this? Workarounds or fixes?

UPDATE: I forgot to add that i did look at rate limits posted by [Xero](http://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/xero-api-limits/), I'm not anywhere close to any of those limits

Answer (score 0):

I think xero API give you the option to save a bunch of tracking categories within one request